# Report Abuse in Twiki website

Tags: security, controls, wiki, twiki

I want to include report abuse button in my website. But couldn't find any such thing in the twiki documentation. Read the entire stuff on twiki variables, access controls, web preferences, but couldn't find anything about such or similar type of button.

Comment: The Wiki way is to have the user edit the page. It seems to me you might be better served by a CMS if your userbase is not cooperative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH, I think this is a really simple suggestion that very few Wiki's have done. It would not be hard to make a simple button that anyone could click...

and so - (assuming that you're not wanting guests to report abuse - given the difficulties wrt security there) - use CommentPlugin to add a line to a common topic that has been set to DENYCHANGE=WikiGuest , and make a custom Comment Template that saves the current %BASEWEB% and %BASETOPIC% to it.

then, add the appropriate COMMENT magic to your custom skin.

ok, so thats mid level magic - I don't know how to do it all without reading docs - perhaps report an enhancement request against CommentPlugin at http://foswiki.org/Tasks...